# What is the purpose of the 'div' selector and why do so many developers use it in their style sheets?

Tags: css, css-selectors

Looking through style sheets from popular & unpopular websites I have found the `div` selector included in them. The bottom four examples were taken from the style sheets of the popular sites *Stack Overflow, Github, Youtube* & *Twitter*:

```
div.form-item-info{padding:4px 0 4px 4px;width:80%;color:#777;}


.searchFooterBox div span.smallLabel{font-size:14px}


#readme.rst div.align-right{text-align:left;}


.hentry .actions>div.follow-actions{visibility:visible;text-align:left;}
```

I find that I can design fully functioning CSS style sheets with out using the `div` selector so the question is:

**What is the `div` selector's function?**
 &
 **Why do so many developers use it?**

*EDIT:*

To be clear, when using the `div` selector, what does it mean when `div` appears before an **id** or **class**? 
*For example:*

```
div.foo { color:black; }
div#bar { color:gray; }
```

And what does it mean when `div` appears after an **id** or **class**? 
*For example:*

```
.foo div { color:black; }
#bar div { color:gray; }
```

When the `div` selector appears after an id or class does it have to have another selector appear after it? 
*For example:*

```
#foo div span { color:black; }
#foo div p { color:black; }
```

Comment: Which one of those four websites was the *unpopular* one?

Comment: Well I only said that I found the div selector in popular and unpopular sites. I did not specify whether or not my examples where of the popular or unpopular nature. Besides, this is kind of off topic. Still, sorry to confuse you. I will edit it.

Comment: @j3m The confusing thing about the question, is that div selector in CSS refers to div tags in HTML.  The more general question question to ask would be: why do sites specify HTML elements in CSS selectors, instead of simply relying on classes and IDs?

Comment: @George right but when 'div' appears in a CSS stylesheet isn't it known as a CSS selector in that context?

Comment: @j3m Yeah, it's an element selector, as opposed to a class or ID selector.  It depends on the existence of said element in the HTML source to which you're applying that CSS.  Similarly, the class or the ID needs to exist in the HTML source in order for the CSS to apply to them.  The basic difference is that the developer/designer determines the *name* **and** existence of classes/IDs in the sources.  However, for HTML elements, the names are determined by the standard and only their existence in the source is determined by the developer/designer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. Being more explicit in your selector makes it easier to remember what the HTML structure is like. Months down the line I can read the CSS and based on my explicit rules I can automatically map the structure in my head without going back to the HTML.
2. By specifying the node name before the class or ID, the rule becomes more specific. If you want to override `.foo { color:black; }` for a div that has a class of foo, just do `div.foo { color:red; }`. Paragraphs that have a class of `foo` would be black, while divs would be red.
3. It can be useful if you want to serve different css rules based on HTML structure. In the rules below, Any span inside a div is red. Any direct span under `#foo` is blue.

CSS:

```
#foo div span { color:red; }
#foo span { color:blue; }
```

html for that:

```
<div id="foo"><span>blah</span> <div><span>blah</span></div> </div>
```

Live demo that you can play around with: http://jsfiddle.net/6dw2r/

**EDIT:**

1. div#foo matches a div with an id of foo.
2. div#foo div means any div descendants of #foo.
3. No. It doesn't.

Please read http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#pattern-matching for further questions.

Comment: While what you said is valid, you didn't actually answer his question.

Comment: He's asking about `div` being used in selectors. How is my answer not relevant?

Comment: @meder So the first 'blah' would be colored 'blue' and the second 'blah' would be colored 'red'. Correct?

Comment: @meder Also, In the 4 examples I included the 'div' selector appears before the classes like 'div.form-item-info'. Can you write your example like 'div#foo span'? And can you write my included example like '.form-item-info div'?

Comment: Yes, you can specify the node name before the id or class.

Comment: Nice one meder - good explanation. @helixed - not sure what you're on about :)

Comment: @meder thank you very much. you have enlightened me. And thanks for the jsfiddle link. Nice and handy tool. Wish the updates happened in real time though.

Comment: @Marko I believe @helixed was referring to @meder's first answer which was not as complete in answering my question as it is now.

Comment: I misunderstood the question the first time I saw it. The edits helped too.  My bad. Vote reversed.

Answer (score 4):

```
div.form-item-info{...} // all div elements that have class~=form-item-info

.form-item-info{...}  // all elements that have class~=form-item-info
```

Answer (score 2):

In HTML and XHTML, <div> and <span> are generic container elements. <div> is a block-level element. <span> is an inline element.

Most other elements (<h1>, <p>, <strong>, etc.) have specific semantic meanings. It's bad practice to use, say, a <p> element for something that's not a paragraph. But <div> is just a container.

If you need something to be purely decorative, or to group related elements, <div> is a good choice.

Comment: I think the question is why people declare div#header vs just #header. Not what a DIV is. I am truly amazed this received 5 upvotes :/

Comment: The <header> tag is new in HTML5. It doesn't exist in XHTML 1.0/1.1 or XHTML4.01.

Comment: @Paul Schreiber I was refering to the 'div' selector that is often included in a CSS style sheet, not the 'div' tag that is included in html.

Comment: Ooops. Misread. But: div#header has a higher CSS specificity score than just #header. And: you might have a div#header and a ul#header (or whatnot).

Comment: Technically you shouldn't, since ID's should be unique. And I'm sorry I feel like I'm bullying you :/

Comment: @Paul Schreiber so is having p#header { color: green } & <p id="header"></p> the same as having #header p { color: green } & <div id="header"><p></p></div> essentially? Or is one version more specific than the other?

Comment: In the absence of any other CSS rules, the two examples you've given will behave identically.

Answer (score 1):

> The  tag defines a division or a
>   section in an HTML document.
>
> The  tag is often used to group
>   block-elements to format them with
>   styles.

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_div.asp

They're just being explicit about their selectors, which tends to be a good thing, as you're being more specific when addressing the elements to be styled.  (Smaller chance of conflicts and unintended styling.)

Answer (score 1):

```
div.foo { rule }
div#bar { rule }
```

This means the rule only applies to div elements with class foo or id bar, and the rule would not apply to non-div elements with class foo or id bar.

```
.foo div { rule }
#bar div { rule }
```

This means the rule applies to all div elements inside any element with class foo or id bar. This is called a **descendant selector**.

```
#foo div span { rule }
#foo div p { rule }
```

When a div selector appears after an id or class, it is not required to have another selector after it. If there is such a selector, the rule will apply to the selected elements only if they are inside a div element which is inside an element having id foo.

You may want to read up on your selectors here:

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html

Comment: great job at explaining the div selector and descendant selectors. thanks